# Permission Denial while attempting to access content provider

Tags: android

I am attempting to access a Content Provider that is in created in App1 from App2. But am getting the following error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading providers.RTBContentProvider uri content://com.xxx.xxx.providers.RTBContentProvider/levelGoal from pid=30764, uid=10175 requires com.xxx.xxx.READ_DATABASE, or grantUriPermission()
```

In App1's manifest I have the following code relating to the provider

```
<permission  android:name="com.xxx.xxx.READ_DATABASE" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>

<provider android:authorities="com.xxx.xxx.providers.RTBContentProvider"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true"
          android:name="providers.RTBContentProvider"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"                    
          android:readPermission="com.xxx.xxx.READ_DATABASE"/>
```

And in App2 I am granting the permission via

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.READ_DATABASE"/>
```

Any idea's are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally put the  element inside of the  element. After changing that I have no issues.